# Log storage location ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder, elastic-stack

I am doing centralized logging using logstash. I am using logstash-forwarder on the shipper node and ELK stack on the collector node.I wanted to know the location where the logs are stored in elasticsearch i didn't see any data files created where the logs are stored.Do anyone has idea about this?

Comment: check your `path.data` parameter in your elasticsearch.yml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Login to the server that runs Elasticsearch
2. If it's an ubuntu box, open the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
3. Check out the path.data configuration
4. The files are stored on that location

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Tomer but the default path to logs in case of ubuntu is

```
/var/log/elasticsearch.log
/var/log/elasticsearch-access.log
/var/log/elasticsearch_deprecation.log
```

In **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml** the path to data path is commented out by default.

So the default path to logs is `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `path.data` will be where Elasticsearch stores its data (in your case indexed logs) and `path.logs` is where Elasticsearch stores its own logs.

If you can't find elasticsearch.yml, you can have a look at the command line, where you'll find something like `-Des.path.conf=/opt/elasticsearch/config`

If `path.data`/`path.logs` aren't set, they should be under a `data`/`logs` directory under `path.home`. In my case, the command line shows `-Des.path.home=/opt/elasticsearch`